# Context getting mixed in $.deferred.promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have the following code;

```
function myFunction(promiseObject){
     var that = this;

     promiseObject
        .done(function(){
                 //using that here
              });
}
```

The above function gets called in multiple context and hence value for `this` changes in every call. The issue I am facing is that for many concurrent calls, the value for `that` gets overridden by another context which is also in process of completion.

I wanted to understand what could be the reason for this. Also wanted to understand that what is the concept behind scope of `that` variable defined in `myFunction` but used in the attached callback method.

Thanks in advance :)

-devsri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that I understand your problem correctly.  The concept behind the `that` variable being defined in `myFunction` and being accessible in the callback is lexical scoping at work.  It's creating a closure (basically a reference to the execution environment of the function that the callback is defined in) for the callback to access.

The value of `this` inside of `myFunction` is going to depend on how you are calling `myFunction`.

If you want a `myFunction` to have a specific context you'll need to call it with that context like so:

```
var myContext = { foo: "bar" };
myFunction.call(myContext);
```

The value of `this` inside of myFunction will now be equal to `myContext`.

If you want your value of `that` to remain consistent between calls you'll need to make sure you call/apply `myFunction` with the correct context everywhere.

Alternatively you can use a function like underscore.js's `_.bind`:

```
myFunction = _.bind(myFunction, myContext);
```

`myFunction` will now always be bound to a specific context.

Comment: Caleb, variables in a closure are not copies. An outer function's execution context, including all its local vars and any other vars which are in scope, are **kept alive** by the existence of a persistent reference to an inner function. (That's pretty close to the definition of a *lexical closure*.) Copies are not made.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot edited my answer.  I shouldn't have sacrificed technical accuracy in order to help him understand. Thanks!

Comment: Caleb, that's as complete an answer as Devsri could hope for. I was going to post something very similar but wouldn't have known to include the bit about `_.bind()` -  thank you for that. The only things you might add are a better intro to `.apply()` and a link to somewhere that explains `.call()` and `.apply()` in more detail.